# Problem with deployment of Cube in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, deployment, olap-cube

Don't know how to solve these errors. Looking for help.

**Errors:**

Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.

Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The process operation ended because the number of errors encountered during processing reached the defined limit of allowable errors for the operation.

Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while processing the 'COVID19' partition of the 'COVID19' measure group for the 'COVID19' cube from the COVID19DM2 database.

Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.

Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key cannot be found when processing: Table: 'COVID19', Column: 'FK_Country', Value: '1'. The attribute is 'Country'.

Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The record was skipped because the attribute key was not found. Attribute: Country of Dimension: Country from Database: COVID19DM2, Cube: COVID19, Measure Group: COVID19, Partition: COVID19, Record: 1.

Comment: the error is in details: The attribute key cannot be found when processing: Table: 'COVID19', Column: 'FK_Country', Value: '1'. The attribute is 'Country'.
it means that you have in your fact table a reference to your country dimension with the value 1 wich does not exists in your dimension

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.